# Set div's minimum height

Tags: html, css

I wanted to ask how I can define a div's minimum height in css.

For example if I am on a small screen and the line break has changed, the div should be automatically resized, but it should be at least 100%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `min-height` to keep the div height 100% or higher like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="someName">
    <!-- child elements -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.someName {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help Scrumplex :)